# How to use CreateJS / Tween in order to affect both X and Y for Parallax on mouse moves?

Tags: javascript, parallax, createjs, tween, animate-cc

I'm trying to get a bit of code (I found in a tutorial) that does parallax on X axis to also affect Y axis according to mouse moves.. only I am very new to JavaScript syntax and don't know how to implement this.
I have only 2 layers I want to move accordingly(level0 and level2). 
So far I could not manage to have BOTH X and Y axis to move as a result.. it only wants to affect one axis at a time.

Can you figure out how to affect Y axis as well as X ?

I tried doubling the function after the first one is fired. Not working.

Please please please.. any hint would be highly appreciated.

```
stage.on("stagemousemove", throttle( function(evt) {

    var hOffset = (evt.stageX - env.compWidth/2) * 2;
    // the following bit I wrote (only this one line right here)    
    var hOffsetY = (evt.stageY - env.compHeight/2) *2;
    // Tween layers with distanceFactor 
    createjs.Tween.get(content.level0, {override:true}).to({x: env.level0_initialX - (hOffset / 25) }, 1072, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);   
    createjs.Tween.get(content.level2, {override:true}).to({x: env.level2_initialX - (hOffset / 18) }, 1072, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);
    },100));
```

Comment: It looks like your tweens are identical, affecting the `x` property...

Comment: @Lanny it's not :
'(hOffset / 25)'
'(hOffset / 18)'
I'm using a division to affect differently each of the 2 layers. 
But this is however not addressing the question at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `y` tween in the same `Tween.to()` call on each layer.

```
stage.on("stagemousemove", throttle( function(evt) {

    // Determine the horizontal and vertical offset
    var hOffset = (evt.stageX - env.compWidth/2) * 2;
    var hOffsetY = (evt.stageY - env.compHeight/2) *2;

    // Tween layers with distanceFactor 
    createjs.Tween.get(content.level0, {override:true}).to({
        x: env.level0_initialX - (hOffset / 25),
        y: env.level0_initialY - (hOffsetY / 25) // <------------------ here
    }, 1072, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);   
    createjs.Tween.get(content.level2, {override:true}).to({
        x: env.level2_initialX - (hOffset / 18),
        y: env.level2_initialY - (hOffsetY / 18) 
    }, 1072, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);

},100));
```

If you simply duplicate the two tweens it will not work because this example is set up to clear out tweens any time it is run (using `override:true`). This prevents multiple tweens from trying to affect the same object at the same time.

Note that tweens aren't really the best solution for something like this where you are constantly re-running it when the mouse moves. A better solution is to just have a function on tick that constantly moves your layers towards a target, which is updated on mousemove. Often parallax effects react directly to the mouse too, instead of drifting into place.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks a lot @Lanny ! Spot on. 
The only problem is that the value '1072' refers to the stage width and Y values should be linked to Stage Height '460' and not 1072. 
I just don't know how to integrate this 460 value.. IF I got the algorithm right... 
But you definitely helped me take a giant leap there ! thank you.

Comment: Ah. You would need 2 separate tweens. The key is to only set `override:true` on the first tween for each object, so it wipes out other active tweens. Then the following tween runs concurrently.